# How can I trace a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) at `admin/reports/status`?

Tags: wsod, log-messages

I get a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) at **admin/reports/status**

I see no errors at **admin/reports/dblog**

How can I trace this?

Comment: check directory `/var/logs/httpd` and find `error_log`, 500 error probably - server Unable to handle your request OR may be problem with .htaccess file maybe redirection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Apache/nginx/other server error log, 500 errors almost always appear in there.

As neok notes, checking the validity of your .htaccess file would also be a good thing to do. If required extensions are missing for .htaccess directives a 500 error is often the result